# getimagefile() in smarty template working randomly

Tags: php, smarty

In a photo gallery template (CMSMS) I use this code:

```
<ul>
{foreach from=$images item=image}
{$imagesize=getimagesize($image->file)}
<li> name : {$image->file} <em>width :</em> {$imagesize[0]}- <em>height:</em> {$imagesize[1]} </li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Each time the gallery is loaded, only the sizes (width and height) of a few images are retrieved, sometimes all of them. It's completely random and not necessarily the same images. I obviously tried with different images from different sources.

I have a failed to open stream error: connection denied.
Ctrl+F5 gives randomly
[image]

[image]

[image]

It's a shared hosting (OVH).

I created a php file at the root of my site and a directory of images ( many).

```
 <?php

function walkDir($path = null) {
    if(empty($path)) {
        $d = new DirectoryIterator('./testqdima');
    } else {
        $d = new DirectoryIterator($path);
    }

    foreach($d as $f) {
        if(
            $f->isFile() && 
            preg_match("/(\.gif|\.png|\.jpe?g)$/", $f->getFilename())
        ) {
            list($w, $h) = getimagesize($f->getPathname());
            echo "<p>".$f->getFilename() . " Dimensions: " . $w . ' ' . $h . "</p>";
        } elseif($f->isDir() && $f->getFilename() != '.' && $f->getFilename() != '..') {
            walkDir($f->getPathname());
        }
    }
}

walkDir();

?>
```

It works perfectly, all images are alway processed.

So if anyone has had this problem before...

Comment: Do you access the image via an URL or via a local path? It looks like you access the image via an URL and the HTTP request might just fail. `getimagesize()` will return `false` in such a case.

Comment: you seem to be accessing the same site multiple times in quick succession. You might be hitting a rate limiter or something.

Comment: Cache the image sizes instead of doing a realtime getimagesize() each time.

Answer (score 0):

Many hosting service providers will impose Connection Limit and/or Connection Rate Limit (or similar ways) to tackle DDOS attack (or due to resource allocation consideration).

For Connection Rate Limit, it is:

```
Connection Rate Limit: a number that specifies the number of 
new connections accepted per second for the virtual server.
```

They may also impose other methods to limit the number of PHP calls / specific PHP method calls per seconds.

For the templating method, **each** call to the `getimagesize` is a **separate** request, hence may trigger the limit restriction and cause connection denied error

For the PHP way, it is regarded as a single request and hence it goes thru successfully.

I think you can only fix the problem by talking to the hosting company (but they may not entertain you because they still need to tackle likely DDOS, etc.) , otherwise please stick to your PHP way of parsing the image records (or switch to another hosting company / use a dedicated server)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It does not suit me, it is not easy to ask the developer of the module to add 2 fields to the database just for the use of Photoswipe which uses this data. I will try to see with OVH but I have little hope.